# Flex 4.5 JSON check for existence of key before exception?

Tags: json, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

Is it possible to check for the existence of a key before Flex 4.5 JSON throws an exception for key not found? I have some json data where some keys are not always present.

I am using CallResponder...

The issue is that when you try accessing `callResponder.lastResponse.key` - and, say, key is not always present in your json, Flex won't be able to parse it. This happens even if you check `if (callResponder.lastResponse.key)` - the error occurs on the if line, in that case

---

(See [old error dump here](http://pastebin.com/F7u8S61z))

---

The answer provided below works for cases where the keys are top level nodes in the JSON. However, its seems unable to parse existence for child keys. I had not expected there to be a difference between parsing for top level nodes and child nodes, but apparently that is the case.

For clarity's sake (as I did not mention I am trying to parse for child keys in my original question), I've created a new question here that specifically asks how to parse for child keys, using the method below -- or another method, if need be:  [Flex 4.5 How do you check for JSON child node key existence (using hasOwnProperty or other methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290577/flex-4-5-how-do-you-check-for-json-child-node-key-existence-using-hasownpropert)

Comment: Show your code that is throwing the error.

Comment: I used CallResponder.lastResult (etc). If you assign `bob=callresponse.lastResult.bob`, then that line will cause the bug, when your json call has no bob key defined. Is there a way to detect if that key exists in the json first?

Comment: can you show us more code than that?  For example, what is bob in that snippet?

Comment: bob is just a string... it usually always works if the json key is defined..

Comment: Then maybe you should check to see if the json key is defined?  Make sure that lastResult has a defined value, too.

Comment: well, the json data source sometimes has the key defined, but not always. how do you check (in flex) if a key is defined?

Comment: Check to see if it exists something like this:   if(callresponse.lastResult.bob){ // exists } else { // no exist }

Comment: Tried that ... that doesn't work. Flex can't access .bob if the key is not defined in the json...

Comment: It would be too amazing if CallResponder does not have a method to check for key existence or not and just throws an exception otherwise; there are a lot of cases where the JSON returned might or might not contain a certain key.  @www.flextras.com you really ought to check using your snippet with a CalLResponder, then debug to see for yourself that Flex breaks right on the conditional check when there is an undefined key.

Comment: I don't think it's the responsibility of CallResponder to check the key. CallResponder is just an asynchronous responder, and CallResponder.lastResult gives you the result. As soon as you got the result, its work is done.

Comment: well, how do you check if a key exists using the CallResponder framework... I guess I just need to know what to access to check the key.

Comment: @ina provide me a code sample that demonstrates your problem that I can copy and paste to run [preferably a single file] and I'll take a look.

Comment: Actually, kyohiro almost has it below, but we are still trying to figure out how to use hasOwnProperty to reference the existence of the child of a child in a JSON. (Seems to only work for top level nodes.)  See comments in kyrohiro's thread below.

Comment: (Updated my question to include yet more info...)

Comment: I guess checking for keys for child node might be a different question, well here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290577/flex-4-5-how-do-you-check-for-json-child-node-key-existence-using-hasownproperty

Comment: @ina You don't have to open a new question if the answers to this one aren't sufficient. You can edit this question instead to emphasize the fact that you want a solution that covers child keys as well. There's not much harm in doing it either way, though, so it's up to you. Just remember that you don't have to accept an answer until you're 100% satisfied with it. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I think the correct answer for child nodes might involve something much longer - I'm not sure if Flex can actually parse child node key existence!!!  It seems that all the Flex examples that deal with data/JSON online seem to only parse existence of top level nodes. This is really odd, since it's not that uncommon for JSON data sources to have many child nodes. There's always some politics involved with S/O and people seeming to want to help only if they have a chance for points, so I hope the new question specifically on child node feels worthwhile for them to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you process your JSON data?

In my memory, I use JSON.decode(String), and got an array. For each object, you can use obj.hasOwnProperty(key) to check whether it's present.

Comment: I used CallResponder.lastResult (etc)

Comment: Could you give an answer relevant to the CallResponder object that is in Flex 4.5?

Comment: The issue is that using CallResponder, you are supposed to reference things using lastResponse, and lastResponse does not have an hasOwnProperty method.. Are you using Flex 4.5?

Comment: Just a note, I have tried variations of callresponder.hasOwnProperty(callresponder.lastResult.location.name) (where the JSON has a location key with a name sub-level), and also callresponder.hasOwnProperty("lastResult.location.name"), and they all do not work.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work or not but your way of calling hasOwnProperty is definitely wrong. callresponder.lastResult.hasOwnProperty("location")

Comment: And I don't know what do you mean by lastResult does not have hasOwnProperty method. lastResult is declared as lastResult:*, so it can be any type, of course IDE won't tell you what method it has. hasOwnProperty is a method defined in EcmaScript standard and implemented in Object class.

Comment: okay, I think I see the issue right now.. hasOwnProperty does not work for checking for a key that is child of key: location. Or, it could be that I am referencing it wrong again -  is this ther ight way to do it: `callresponderlastResult.hasOwnProperty("location.name")` to specify the JSON key called "name", that is a child of the key location