# Flex 4.5 How do you check for JSON child node key existence (using hasOwnProperty or other methods)

Tags: json, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

How do you check for JSON child node key existence using hasOwnProperty (or other methods) in Flex 4.5?

The `hasOwnProperty` method can check for JSON key existence but this seems to only work with top level nodes in a JSON, and not the child nodes. For example, if you have JSON structure like this (in a readable form, sans the JSON syntax), you can check for the existence of `callresponder.lastResponse.hasOwnKey("Location")`, but there seems no way to check for `Location.VenueName` for example or any of the children:

```
Name: 
Location: 
  (child) VenueName: 
  (child) Address: 
      (child) City: 
      (child) State: 
  .
  .
  . (etc)
```

The issue is that my data source omits the child key when the information is not available,  so it would be nice to be able to check for the existence of the JSON key in a reference in Flex before doing anything else for it.

The obvious `callresponder.lastResponse.hasOwnKey("Location.VenueName")` does not work.

**Q: How would I check if the JSON key `Location.VenueName` exists?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex 4.5 JSON check for existence of key before exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206990/flex-4-5-json-check-for-existence-of-key-before-exception)

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Well, you told me in previous comments I ought to give "correct answer" votes quickly, rather than wait for an answer that fully works. The previous question worked partially, but the solution provided does not work for child keys. Posting a more specific version for this different case seemed appropriate... You seem to be one of the few people here who answer Flex questions, so I'm trying to play nice here. I don't see why you're voting this closed.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think we all learn something more about programming here, so if you can't answer a particular question (no matter how basic it seems), you don't have to feel bad about it, but maybe someone here might be able to help both of us figure it out!

Comment: I've updated the linked question to explain for the branch-off. I have also updated the current question to be more open minded -- maybe something other than `hasOwnProperty` should be used

Comment: I'm not sure when I told you that you should give "correct answer" votes quickly if the answer is incomplete or wrong.  That doesn't help you, nor people who have the same question in the future.  I'm sorry if I miscommunicated.  From my perspective; this question covers all the same topics of your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Even more obvious would be

```
callresponder.lastResult.Location.hasOwnProperty("VenueName");
```

Which should work.

Comment: thank you! `callresponder.lastResult.Location.hasOwnProperty("VenueName");` worked. :-)

Comment: on second look, it still does not work. voted up too early :-( and back to staring at the drawing board :-(